# Element stays in hover state when moving the pointer quickly out of the window

Tags: javascript, css, hover, reactjs, openfin

I'm working on an app using openfin and react. It is a toolbar containing multiple elements in a row. I have one near the edge that needs to change its background color when the user hovers his pointer over it. The problem is that quick movements to the left or up/down(and out of the window) leave the element in a *hover* state.

I tried using javascript, but `onmouseout` has the same problem. What's odd is that I have several elements containing images in the same toolbar that don't have this problem.

Any ideas?

*Edit:* HTML/JSX:

```
<div>
    <Component1 /> // 80x80-ish
    <MyComponent /> // 20x80-ish wxh
    <OtherComponents />
</div>
```

MyComponent is the one that's acting up. The css is simply changing `background-color` on `:hover` on the outermost div of the component. Sorry I can't get very specific.

Right now the components are flush with the edge of the window (no border or anything). I'm thinking that I might need to add a couple of pixels there.

*Edit2:* Just noticed that *Component1* has `webkit-app-region: drag`. That contributes to the problem because *MouseOut* doesn't always trigger when moving from a regular element to that one.

**I fixed the problem** by shrinking the component so *MouseOut* has some space to trigger (5px was enough in my case).

Comment: Is the element the leftmost in the toolbar?

Comment: Add the code as well...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $('#element').hover(function() {
  $(this).css({'background':'red'});
   }, function() {
   $(this).css({'background':'none'});
   }) ;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I'm not using jquery in this project and I'm not sure how nice this would play with react.